# SQL: How do I display all records per unique id, but not the first record ever recorded in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Example:
id        Pricemoney      time/date

1       100              01/20/2017
1       10               01/21/2017
1       1000             01/21/20147
2       10               01/23/2017
2       100              01/24/2017
3       1000             01/19/2017
3       100              01/22/2017
3       10               01/24/2017
```

I want to run a SQL query where I can display all the Id and it's pricemoney BUT NOT include the first record (based on time/date) per unique

Just to clarify what I do not want to be displayed

```
userid        Pricemoney      issuedate

1       100              01/20/2017 -- not included
1       10               01/21/2017
1       1000             01/21/20147
2       10               01/23/2017 --- not inlcuded
2       100              01/24/2017
3       1000             01/19/2017 -- not included
3       100              01/22/2017
3       10               01/24/2017
```

Expected result:

```
id        Pricemoney      time/date

1       10               01/21/2017
1       1000             01/21/20147
2       100              01/24/2017
3       100              01/22/2017
3       10               01/24/2017
```

Comment: Select * from table order by id desc, time/date desc    But when i have used max and other not in commands I have just ended up with the wring output

Comment: Where does the "Count" come into this that you mention in your Subject? Also, what date does `01/21/20147` represent?

Comment: How does a simple `Select * from table;` help? The OP wants filtered results.

Comment: sorry ignore count! I want to display all records per unique id, but not the first record ever recorded in SQL

Comment: Hint: COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [time/date]) AS rank... To create a ranking. And use a subquery  with filter WHERE rank > 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time_date asc) as seqnum
      from <tablename> t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

If you want to keep single rows, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time_date asc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from <tablename> t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1 and cnt > 1;
```

Comment: sorry ignore count! I want to display all records per unique id, but not the first record ever recorded in SQL

Comment: @hlch123 . . . These queries should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXISTS`

```
select t1.*
from data t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from data t2
    where t1.id = t2.id and t2.time_date < t1.time_date
)
```

Comment: could you please be more specific with what you mean with what data you are calling when you refer to t. * and t2 etc @Radim Bača

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are just aliases of your table. your table is used twice so I assign two different aliases in order to distinguish them

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
select data1.id,data1.Date,data1.Pricemoney  from data1
        left join (
                    select id ,min(Date) date from data1
                    group by id
                  ) as t
        on data1.date= t.date and t.id = data1.id
        where t.id is null
        group by data1.id,data1.Date,data1.Pricemoney
```

above query not duplicated records also ignore, if want 
not duplicated records then use **having count(id) > 1** in left query e,g.

```
select data1.id,data1.Date,data1.Pricemoney  from data1
        left join (
                    select id ,min(Date) date from data1
                    group by id
                     having COUNT(id) > 1
                  ) as t
        on data1.date= t.date and t.id = data1.id
        where t.id is null
        group by data1.id,data1.Date,data1.Pricemoney
```

Comment: "Data1" with left join "t" to match records(date,id)  if match than "t" in saw the record other wise is "null".  so here i fiter record "t.id is null". if you don't know what the record in "t" let' me clear first. "t" in minimum date, id as per id(uniq id) .

Comment: Simpli i'm here getting first min date and id as per id and join table with original record. so here using left join map with record if its match then "t.id is not null" other wise "null".  now in "t"  available fist row of the data as per id. thats all record are ignore .